# How to add bluetooth in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, device, core-bluetooth

I would like to know how to add bluetooth in my app. I know I'll need to import "CoreBluetooth." I just want to play some sounds and able to hear it on another device using bluetooth. I already looked up on Apple's website. I don't like going to Apple's website because it requires releasing. My app doesn't accept the word release because ARC is enable. Please help me.

Comment: use **GameKit.framework** and import it .synchronizing peers and sending data. look at **GKSessionDelegate, GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate** set connectionTypesMask .

Answer (score 2):

A lot of of Bluetooth networking boilerplate is taken care of in GameKit, including synchronizing peers and sending data. I'd recommend taking a look at [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also, if you're using a code snippet that was written pre-ARC in an ARC app, you can effectively ignore *release* statements (though in some cases you will need to make sure you aren't retaining a reference to an object after it is not needed).

Comment: Last night I was reading a book that allow me to connect to other iDevices. I tried adding the code to my app, but it started looking for other iDevices. I would like my app to connect to speakers that has bluetooth. Thanks anyway!